# how to select distinct rows for a column

Tags: sql

I have a table `x` that's like the one bellow:

```
id | name | observed_value |
1  | a    | 100            |
2  | b    | 200            |
3  | b    | 300            |
4  | a    | 150            |
5  | c    | 300            |
```

I want to make a query so that in the result set I have exactly one record for one name:

```
  (1, a, 100)
  (2, b, 200)
  (5, c, 300)
```

If there are multiple records corresponding to a name, say 'a' in the table above, I just pick up one of them.

In my current implementation, I make a query like this:

```
select x.* from x , 
(select distinct name, min(observed_value) as minimum_val
from x group by name) x1
where x.name = x1.name and x.observed_value = x1.observed_value;
```

But I think there may be some better way around, please tell me if you know, thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

I am using MySQL and my table contains more than the three columns shown here, so it seems to me that the inner query can not fulfill my requirement.

Comment: I'm positive this has been asked before, but I can't find it :(

Comment: Which database engine are you using (e.g. MySQL, MS-SQL)?

Comment: The distinct in your inner query is extraneous, group by will guarantee that you will only get distinct values. Any duplicates will be grouped together.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT  t.*
FROM    (
        SELECT  DISTINCT name
        FROM    mytable
        ) q
JOIN    mytable t
ON      t.id =
        (
        SELECT  id
        FROM    mytable ti
        WHERE   ti.name = q.name
        ORDER BY
                ti.name, ti.observed_value, ti.id
        LIMIT 1
        )
```

Create an index on `(name, observed_value, id)` for this query to be efficient.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. But when I run this, it is slower than my current query which is in my question descritpion.

Comment: @Satoru: did you create the index I suggested?

Comment: Not yet. But I think my solution will also speed up if I create those indexes, or am I missing something?

Comment: @Satoru: yes it will. Your solution, BTW, is fine, unless it's possible for your model to have duplicates of `observed_value`. For instance, if record `4` had observed value of `100` (instead of `150`), your solution would return two records for `a`, while mine is guaranteed to return only one (in case of a tie, the least id is returned). You may want to read this article in my blog: http://explainextended.com/2009/11/25/mysql-selecting-records-holding-group-wise-maximum-resolving-ties/

Comment: Thanks, your explanation is insightful to me :)

Comment: Thanks, managed to use this sql in a similar case where I had two columns for the `distinct` clause :-)

Answer (score 1):

Use just group by

```
select id, name, min(observed_value) as minimum_val  from x group by name;
```

Comment: This query will result in an error: column id is not part of the group by clause and there is no aggregate function specified for it.

Comment: @Tommi Unless the OP is using MySQL

Comment: @Martin: in `MySQL`, this query will not fail, however, `MIN(observed_value)` and `id` are not guaranteed to originate from the same record (and most probably won't)

Answer (score 1):

Since you didn't specify which DBMS you are using, I'll provide a couple of solutions:

If you are using a DBMS that has the `FIRST()` aggregate function, you could use:

```
SELECT 
  FIRST(id) as id, 
  name, 
  FIRST(observed_value) as observed_value 
FROM x
GROUP BY name;
```

If you are using MySQL, you could use `ORDER BY` in conjunction with `LIMIT` to get something similar to a `FIRST()` aggregate function.

```
SELECT
  ( SELECT x2.id 
    FROM x as x2 
    WHERE x2.name = x.name 
    ORDER BY observed_value ASC 
    LIMIT 1
  ) AS id,
  name,
  MIN(observed_value) as observed_value
FROM x
GROUP BY name
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query looks to be too complex for your purpose... just group the query by column name, and use an aggregate function for rest of the columns. For example

```
SELECT name, min(id), min(observed_value) FROM x GROUP BY name
```

(Obviously, choose aggregate function other than `min` if you want to get other values for each name.)